# MySQL: Conditional Order By

Tags: mysql

I have a column called first_name in my 'employee' table.

I would like to select & order those names by **DESC** **if** COUNT(first_name) is an **odd** number or select & order those names by **ASC** **if** COUNT(first_name) is an **even** number.

Something like that is written below

```
SELECT first_name
FROM employee
ORDER BY (first_name DESC if COUNT (first_name) % 2 != 0 ELSE first_name ASC);
```

Comment: Help us help you - share some sample data and the result you'd want to get for it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to force mysql to choose one option

like

```
SELECT first_name
FROM employee
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(first_name) % 2 <> 0 THEN first_name END) ASC,
         (CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(first_name) % 2 =  0 THEN first_name END) DESC
```

It can only be one or the other.